# Not able to open second page of my wpf browser application in a new browser window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to wpf.I am doing a browser application in wpf and i wanted to know if i can open my second page in a new browser window.

I am able to open a new browser window using system windows diagnostics.process statement and i am able to load my project also but not the desired page in it.

I am also able to open my  desired page like a aplication using uri.

But what i want is a hybrid of both and i am not able to find anything to suit my purpose.
Thanks in advance mates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
1. Add a new window NewWindow  

2. var newWindow= new NewWindow();
newWindow.Show(); // works

//Or use ShowDialog, if parant wait close of child window
newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I tried what you told but i am getting a error like this "App.page does not contain a definition for show or show dialog also " and also another error that newWindow namespace cannot be found.

Comment: Because newWindow  is your new window, bu you must create newWindow class